Coordinates of Line Criteria
I was reading through a proof for my class and I came across this section:

Along any line $L$, two distinct coordinates $x_i$ and $x_j$ will be equal
either 0 times, 1 time, or at every point on the line. (This is a theorem
from Linear Algebra.)

Can someone help me understand this (I forgot some concepts from Linear Algebra). I constructed an example for a line in 3d space, which has the cases $x=y$, $y=z$, $z=x$. Each of these is a plane, so the statement above is obvious. But can someone help me understand the theorem generally?

The equation $x_i = x_j$ represents a line in three-dimensional space. If a line $L$ is parallel (and not collinear) to the line represented by $x_i = x_j$, then the coordinates $x_i$ and $x_j$ are never equal for the line $L$. If the line $L$ is collinear to the line represented by $x_i = x_j$, then the coordinates $x_i$ and $x_j$ are always equal for the line $L$. If the line $L$ is not parallel to the line represented by $x_i = x_j$, then it will intersect this line at exactly one point, i.e., the coordinates $x_i$ and $x_j$ are equal for the line $L$ at exactly one point.
